# pip python-geohash problem during execution of command

Tags: python-2.7, geohashing

```
pip install python-geohash
```

I get the following **error**:

> Failed building wheel for python-geohash
>
> ....
>   tokenize;file='/private/var/folders/y8/blhw9jx1133b9pyg6jbb4c100000gn/T/pip-install-8c750u/python-geohash/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /private/var/folders/y8/blhw9jx1133b9pyg6jbb4c100000gn/T/pip-record-01O7KL/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/y8/blhw9jx1133b9pyg6jbb4c100000gn/T/pip-install-8c750u/python-geohash/

Can you help me how to download python-geohash. I think it is related to gcc

I use macOS Mojave version 10.14.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the .whl file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-geohash
And use `pip install python_geohash‑0.8.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: just tried this... got: WARNING: Requirement 'python_geohash‑0.8.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: python_geohash‑0.8.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.